# get the route parmas and display default in dropdown in angular 2/4/5 with translations (ngx-translate)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I am looking for the solution to get the route params from the URL and display on the drop-down.

I have tried some solution to get the activatedroute but it's not giving the first value after the baseref.

For example.

localhost:4200/volvo/insert

it should take value from route params as volvo and display the selected as a volvo on dropdown.

same as

localhost:4200/saab/edit

it should take value from route params as saab and display the selected default as a saab on dropdown.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
</select>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about use a **Router** not ActivatedRoute and **split** it

**HTML**

```
<select [(ngModel)]="routeType">
   <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option value="saab">Saab</option>
   <option value="opel">Opel</option>
</select>
```

**Component**

```
@Component({...})
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {

    routeType: string;

    constructor(private router: Router) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
       // router.url will give you /volvo/insert so you can split it and choose the 2nd instance of its resulting array
       this.routeType = this.router.url.split('/')[1];    // volvo
    }

}
```

Comment: using this the volvo option will be double in the html.. so in dropdown we will see 2 times volvo.

Comment: @atitpatel i may not able to understand what you mean but currently the options are static with 3 options and their values and the [(ngModel)] is just there to fetch the current value this select box is assigned to handle. In our case, the routeType ngModel was given a value of "volvo" so the volvo option will be selected and will not be doubled as we didn't run an ngFor for it. Though if you could provide a Stackblitz in regards with the bug you had encountered, i'll be happy go through with it and find a solution :)

Comment: @ KShewengger it's working like charm thanks, the only issue I am facing when I translate the options with ngx-translate. the default value is not showing up. can you please provide your inputs for that?